# AJAX console.log is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined, console.log

I have these two input fields inside a while loop of my database:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ID<?=$product['id'];?>" name="ID" value="<? 
=$product['id'];?>">

<input type="hidden"   id="name<?=$product['id'];?>" name="hidden_name" 
value="<?=$product['title'];?>">
```

Here is the button that triggers the AJAX:

```
<input type="button" class="button" name="cartbtn" id="button<? 
=$product['id'];?>"  value="Quick Add-to-Cart">
```

My problem arises when I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(data){

    $('.button').click(function(){

        var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var product_name = $('#name'+product_id).val();
        console.log(product_name);

    });
});

</script>
```

The `console.log(product_name);` is coming back as undefined.

There is no problem with `var product_id = $(this).attr('id');` if I `console.log(product_id)` it returns: "button6", for example (as it should).

Comment: So, what you're saying is, `$('#namebutton6')` is correctly returning 0 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `console.log(product_id)` returns `button6` that implies that your `product_name` is `namebutton6`. I believe you want it to be `name6`

Since you overcomplicated it, the easiest way to do it is:

```
var product_name = $(`#name${product_id.slice(6)}`).val();
```

You use the `slice(6)` method to remove the first six characters which are `'button'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
id="button<?=$product['id'];?>"
```

Should not have "button" before it, so:

```
id="<?=$product['id'];?>"
```

is correct. I'm oblivious, sorry.

Comment: Actually it probably should, but you should remove the prefix to construct `product_id`.